# Jquery/CSS3 slide up/down page transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so i have a website with multiple pages and a navigation menu with links to the other pages.
i need a Jquery and/or CSS page transition that'll slide the page down, load new page and then slide that page back up.
This would be easy to do if the content of all the pages was in one single page, in different divs, and then i could just make a sort of carousel to show the div corresponding to the link that was clicked. Most of the answers i found applied to that situation. this is not the case though so that wouldn't work and i can't touch the html of the site!
css3 transitions work great when the page loads, but they also need to happen onbeforeunload, which is where the problem lies. i can use jquery to give the divs a class onbeforeunload, which works, but it unloads before the animations even start happening.
I've tried this plugin: 
https://rawgit.com/votum/page-transitions/master/demo/index.html
but it looks very glitchy and doesn't work properly.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out accordion to show content of selected menu item.
https://jqueryui.com/accordion/